# Add an object from a View (Passing from View to Controller)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working in a C# project. In my ReglasDispositivos view there are three diferent actions which a client can do: add a device, update a device and delete once. The controller calls ReglasDispositivos() (get) view passing a ClienteReglasDispositivos model. Lets go, for example, to adding a device. How can i post the info that the client is posting? 
If my view only have one action, I know that I have to add in the controller [HttpPost] and [HttpGet] ReglasDispositivos() method. But when a view has three diferentes actions?

ClientController:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ReglasDispositivos()
        {
            ClienteReglasDispositivos model = new ClienteReglasDispositivos();

            return View(model);
        }
```

ReglasDispositivos view (Adding a device parte) (Im not sure about that BeginForm):

```
@model SistemaGestion.Models.ClienteReglasDispositivos
...
<div class="view-tables">
            <div id="myAdd" class="div-table">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("AgregarDispositivo", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {
                    <fieldset class="fieldset-box">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NombreDispositivo, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "Nombre del dispositivo" });
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HorasDeUso, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass", Placeholder = "KwPorHora" });
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.EsInteligente, new { Class = "YourBackgroundClass" });
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="submit-login" value="AGREGAR" />
                    </fieldset>
                }

            </div>
```

ClienteReglasDispositivos

```
public class ClienteReglasDispositivos
    {
        [Required]
        public string NombreDispositivo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Es inteligente?")]
        public bool EsInteligente { get; set; }
        public double KwPorHora { get; set; }
        public float HorasDeUso { get; set; }
        public string Condicion { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You must each controller action for method type like one for post and second for get.

Comment: You want to use your form to add, update and delete?

Comment: Multiple actions from a single view

Comment: You can have one view but send action to multiple different actions in controller. You can have identical action names but with different inputs (polymorphism).

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple actions with identical name due to polymorphysm. Asp decide what action you call by `[Http(XX)]`.

You can have

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ReglasDispositivos()
{
    ClienteReglasDispositivos model = new ClienteReglasDispositivos();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReglasDispositivos([FromForm] ClienteReglasDispositivos  model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid(model)) {
     //do something
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Also you can call different action name and return same view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ReglasDispositivos()
{
    ClienteReglasDispositivos model = new ClienteReglasDispositivos();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReglasDispositivosPost([FromForm] ClienteReglasDispositivos  model)
{
    return View("ReglasDispositivos", model);
}
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)